# Not cutting hair often okay in office?

Tags: grooming

Is infrequent haircut acceptable in an office environment assuming that there is no rules specifically addressing the issue?  I sometimes wait 4-5 months before getting hair cut so it grows past my ears.

Comment: Go ask HR if they care.

Comment: This question is unanswerable for us. We don't know the country you're in, your culture, the industry, the company, the company culture, your level in the company, your role, whether it's customer-facing or not, and most importantly, we don't know the actual velocity at which your hair grows.

Comment: I haven’t been to the hairdresser in a year and a half and that’s perfectly fine. Context matters.

Comment: I've been in office where it is implicitely asked to have proper hair because clients could come at any moment. In my current job (where I don't see any clients) I haven't been to the hairdresser for 2 years and that is not   an issue.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the role and the workplace culture.

But to generalise, customer facing roles generally require some form of a professional look.

A scruffy looking software dev might be ok but a scruffy looking real estate agent isn't going to make many sales.